# Restore a single SQL Server Temporal table, including the PERIOD columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In testing a data cleanup script, several rows have been deleted.  The table has a temporal pair, but `SYSTEM_VERSIONING` was off at the time, so the history didn't save.  There is a backup, which has most of the lost data, but using the standard single-table restore process (restore the whole backup to a temp, set `IDENTITY_INSERT ON` for the table(s) needed, and `INSERT...SELECT` the rows needed) has a couple of issues:

- If I do a regular insert, the `PERIOD` data will be set to the time of the `INSERT`.  We need to have the `PERIOD` data restored.
- If I `DROP PERIOD`, the period columns will be deleted completely.

Is there a way to temporarily turn off `PERIOD` tracking and allow those columns to be inserted, much like `IDENTITY_INSERT`?

The server in question is running SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Fair enough.  Done.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation for temporal tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modifying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yes, I have already found that article.  There is no indication on how to insert specific values, or modify values, in the PERIOD columns.

A Google search turns up plenty of articles on how to revert ("restore") rows in the main table, using the rows in the history table, but they disregard the loss of PERIOD metadata. We are using the PERIOD data, and need to be able to restore it.

Comment: Because you can't. The current application is _system time_ only, which means you must rely on a date/time supplied by the system at entry time. A future implementation will include _application time_, which will allow you to control those values, but it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to modify or manually insert the period data directly as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modifying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Data in a system-versioned temporal table is modified using regular DML statements with one important difference: **period column data cannot be directly modified.**

In [several places](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modifying-data-in-a-system-versioned-temporal-table?view=sql-server-ver15#updating-data):

> However, you **cannot update PERIOD columns**...

This is because, as the [documentation also explains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver15#what-is-a-system-versioned-temporal-table):

> These period columns are used exclusively by the system to record period of validity for each row whenever a row is modified.

If you were able to modify these period values it would break the validity of these as system-generated timestamps for row updates.

Comment: That's disappointing.  There are numerous other system-generated values (`IDENTITY`, `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, `ROWVERSION`) that can be inserted or updated.  The only difference is that the `PERIOD` columns **can** (but don't have to) be used to refer to a point in time in the history table.

However, the validity argument is moot.  Even if data modifications are done while versioning is turned off, then a validity check is done when versioning is turned back on.  Like other constraints, the DBA should ultimately have control, and responsibility, to ensure that constraint validity is respected.

Comment: Further, in situations like the scenario I am facing, it means that the data **cannot** be restored back to a previously valid state -- the exact problem that backup and restore are meant to rectify -- short of restoring the entire database.  And in doing so, the true historical sequence is lost.